# Fine Uploader and how to highlight extra drop zone area during drag and drop?

Tags: drag-and-drop, fine-uploader

I have successfully added an extra drop zone for Fine Uploader, and that works great.

However I would like to be able to highlight the extra drop zone area in the same way that the default drop zone is highlighted, when a drag and drop operation is started.

I tried adding the qq-upload-drop-area class to my extra drop zone, but of course it colored everything red, whether or not the drag and drop is in progress.

Any pointers as to how to correctly implement this functionality would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [the standalone drag and drop module](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/drag-and-drop.html). Make sure to add a value for the [`classes.dropActive`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/drag-and-drop.html#classes.dropActive) option that matches the class added to the original drag and drop element when it is active.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#fineuploader-traditional').fineUploader({
        // ...
    });

    $(document.body).fineUploaderDnd({
        classes: {
            dropActive: 'qq-upload-drop-area'
        }
    })
    .on('processingDroppedFiles', function(event){
        console.log('Processing');
    })
    .on('processingDroppedFilesComplete', function (event, files, target){
        $("#fineuploader-traditional").fineUploader('addFiles', files);
    });

});
```

What I am doing here is instantiating a new `fineUploaderDnd` instance on the `document.body` (you may want to change this element to something else). I've given it a `dropActive` class of `'qq-upload-drop-area'` which is the default class for the drop area when using Fine Uploader UI (note that you can put *any* class in here -- ideally it would match the class applied to to original dropzone when it is active so that both dropzones match). This class represents the style applied to the drop zone while a file or files are dragged over it.

The `'processingDroppedFilesComplete'` event allows me to add the received files to an instance of Fine Uploader -- where they will validated and eventually uploaded.

**Update**

If you want the contents of any drop zone to be invisible until an item enters the drop zone, simply ensure a `qq-hide-dropzone` attribute is present on the drop zone container.

```
<div id="extra-dropzone" qq-hide-dropzone></div>
```

**Update 2**

Another possible option is to use the `dragAndDrop.extraDropzones` option which will do a lot automatically.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#fineuploader-traditional').fineUploader({
        // ...
        dragAndDrop: {
            extraDropzones: [ $("#extra-dropzone") ]
        },
    });
```

```html
<div id="extra-dropzone" qq-hide-dropzone>
    <h2>Drop files here</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that solution, which I will most likely be implementing.  However before I do, is there a simpler way of just highlighting the added drop zone?  I really just need to know that the user is in the middle of the DnD, and then highlight my drop zone.  I could almost have a nearly hidden traditional FU drop zone, and just watch for it to have the highlighted class... then add the highlight to my drop zone... very hacky... but its just the highlight I need and i'm done.  Otherwise I will implement your solution.

Comment: @sthede -- see my update(s) -- I guess I don't really see how it could be any more simple. I would actually use the 2nd method, unless you need more custom functionality which my first suggested way would be more suited for.

Comment: I have been able to get my extra drop zone to be highlighted while dragging a file over the drop zone.  But mine behaves differently than the default drop area.  The FU template based drop area highlights immediately upon the dragged file entering the browser window.  While trying to move the default drop zone, I noticed that the default drop zone is indeed the size of the screen, yet just the div for the zone is highlighted.  How do I get my extra DnD zone to highlight immediately upon the dragged file entering the browser window, like the default DnD zone?

Comment: Actually I dont know for sure that the default drop zone is full screen, but it does appear to be different because of highlighting immediately upon the DnD entering the browser window, instead of just the DnD area itself.

Comment: The default behavior of the dropzones is to become highlighted upon dragging a file or files into the browser window. This helps to indicate to the user that there are dropzones available on the page. This is different than when the dropzone becomes "active" which is when the user has dragged a file over the actual drop area. This is the behavior I am seeing when using both methods I described above. If you have your javascript code I'd be happy to take a look.